# h2o connect to cluster on hadoop cluster

Tags: java, h2o

I've tried to connect my h2o node to h2o cluster, using -flatfile. It works fine.
But I'm trying now another thing and I've got a problem:

is it possible to connect h2o node to existing h2o cluster which is running on hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about adding a new node to existing H2O cluster (on Hadoop or anywhere), the answer is no. You must list all the IP address first where you want to create H2O nodes and a cluster is formed. H2O does not support dynamic allocation of resources so you can not add a new node to existing H2O cluster.